# Local Notifications - repeating interval(Xcode,swift2)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, datepicker

check my repeat interval code.i think its wrong.I want only users to select time for notifications and its working but it have one more problem that it is repeating after every 13 or 14 or at any minute i don't why so check the code below  and if anyone can help me with weekly and monthly ?

```
   //canceling notifications
func cancelLocalNotificationsWithUUID(uuid: String) {
    for item in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications {
        let notification = item as! UILocalNotification
        if let notificationUUID = notification.userInfo?["UUID"] as? String {
            if notificationUUID == uuid {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func NotificationButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

     cancelLocalNotificationsWithUUID("NotificationID")

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    PickedDate.text = "Your Notification time you choosed is \(strDate)"
   PickedDate.numberOfLines = 0


    var notifications:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notifications.fireDate = datePicker.date
    notifications.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notifications.applicationIconBadgeNumber =    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
    notifications.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    switch(frequencysegmentedcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex){
    case 0:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        break;
    case 1:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear
        break;
    case 2:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth
        break;
    default:
        notifications.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.allZeros
        break;

    }
     notifications.userInfo = ["UUID": "NotificationID"]

    notifications.alertBody = "quote of the day"





  // if user has not confirmed the notification permission
          let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if settings.types == .None {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Can't schedule", message: "Either we don't have permission to schedule notifications, or we haven't asked yet.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notifications)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that rescheduling local notifications with repeat interval does not cancel previous scheduled notifications. This way if you have scheduled daily notifications for more then one time, notification will be triggered more then one time on daily basis. To fix this issue you must manually cancel all previous scheduled notifications by calling :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Comment: check the code now i have done something like this.Should i change UIApllication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification to UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications() @zellb

Comment: Absolutely, thats way better since you are using a single userInfo object

Comment: and can you also check my switch statement cases.I think there is also something wrong @zellb

Comment: Cant see any problem, just be sure that indexes on UISegmentedControl are set properly

Comment: Its working correct now but the weekly case not working @zellb

Comment: Use `.CalendarUnitWeekday` . In your case `.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear` will trigger notification once a year on selected week

Comment: i think i should delete weekly and monthly as it is not working.Thank you so much @zellb

Comment: one more thing if i want datepicker to have to have that time which i have schedule for notification how will i do it?For example i choose 5pm and then when i again open my app at that time the date picker should 5pmonly

Comment: Consider using some persistent method like NSUserDefaults for example and save the date using it